# What options do I have for continuous integration, git project management, and client management

Tags: git, continuous-integration, project-management, bug-tracking

Currently at my work we are using basecamp to manage client projects where they can follow the work being done on a particular project. And we have recently started using git to manage our codebase. So In a lot of ways, basecamp is not enough anymore. I am looking for options out there that will allow us to manage our codebase and projects.

Due to the nature of our projects and various other reasons, we cannot use github or an online hosting solution, but have to use our own server. privately hosted github is far too expensive.

So the features i'm looking for would be the following:

- most or many of what basecamp has. Clients should be able to log in and see updates to the project. As well as post things on the project itself. Such as proposed changes in the project.
- Git project management. This would be seen primarily only by us, not clients, but could be both. But when a client submits a bug or other post, we can internally tie it to a project and commit or file to discuss the issue. We can then track the issue and update the client on the issue. So when the code is fixed the client is notified on status updates.
- Continuous integration. I would like to be able manage the code in a way where it will run tests if there are any (not all of our projects use testing). And when we push to a production branch, it automatically updates the live site with the new code (though I know I can di this with commit hooks in git).
- Optional, But I would like some kind of wiki or notes for a particular project where only we can see it and not clients. Such as reason why some code was changed or in general anything we need to make a note on.

I have looked at rubymine but we don't use ruby and none of us are very familiar with it. So if something goes wrong it will not be worth the time ti fix it. I have looked at trac with the git extension and looks promising.

Another product I have seen that looks nice is You Track and the related products. We only have about 4 developers so I still need to look at what the costs would be.

I am NOT asking which is better. I just want to see what options are out there so I can determine when is right for our case. Primarily we use .Net/C#, PHP, JavaScript, Node.JS. If the system can run on windows that will be a huge plus (current server is windows server), but I am attempting to get us a linux server to run this. So Either option is valid.

So any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a small team, you are eligible for the free licenses to both [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) AND [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) (for continuous integration), both by JetBrains.

I haven't tried YouTrack, but TeamCity is an amazing product IMHO, and I bet both integrate very well.
Our TeamCity is deployed on Windows, and used mainly to build .NET projects as well as automatically deploying them. But it has a vast amount of build runners for different technologies.
Plus, it has some very important advantages over some others that I've used (such as CruiseControl.NET) which are:

- Multiple Build agents for parallel building (3 max in the free edition)
- Nearly everything can be configured through the UI directly

Comment: Yea out of everything I have seen, that product looks really great. I just need to see how much it will cost if we outgrow the free limitations as later in the year we may be hiring more developers anyways.

Comment: Correct. Well, TeamCity is not actually limited by users, but by Build Configurations you can have (20 free). More info [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/buy.jsp). YouTrak can be both Stand-Alone and in the cloud. http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy/index.jsp

You can also checkout Jira: http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview

Comment: Marking as the answer. After looking into the options, jira seems to be the best option for what I need. It also has other tools that work well with it such as confluence, crucible, stash, and bamboo. Since this has to be an internal solution hosted on our servers. thanks for all the input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IBM gives you an out-of-the-box complete solution - 
from requirements to source-control to build-automation and delivery.

See **[Rational Team Concert (4.0)](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/)** on http://jazz.net/ 
(You get 10 licenses free, as part of your review).

The IDE is built on Eclipse, and it works great on Windows and Linux,
and lately I was even able to install the server on Mac
(there are official clients for all 3 platforms).